# Update information is outdated

Tags: updates, printing, canon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I can't remove the red triangle in the right upper corner of my desktop. When I type 
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` 
I get the error message below:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How to fix my problem?

Comment: ... and your question is? I assume you want these errors 404 fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove (or fix) those two lines that cause the error 404. After removing the update process can be started again and it will continue updating.

- [Canon precise page](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-precise).

> Canon printer driver precise
>
> This PPA does not contain any packages yet. Find more information about how to upload packages in the [PPA help page](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA).

This is probably the cause for the error 404 (non existing URL).

There is also:

- [Canon printer driver daily](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-trunk).

  ```
  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu precise main 
  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu precise main
  ```

But I am not sure if this is what you need.

It could also be this that you need:

- [Canon printer drivers 2012](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-2012)

Though these only seem valid for Oneiric.

Comment: Thanks it works properly. I will observe it in 3 days to make sure the red triangle will not appear again.

Comment: excellent @user85821 .As long as your source list is OK the red triangle shall not return ;-)